# Connect parent bone tail to child head

Tags: python, armature, bones

I'd like to connect the tail of a parent bone to the head of a child bone, because it looks more organized.

This is how it currently looks like

[image: how it looks like]

This is how it should look like

[image: how it should look like]

Since there are a lot of bones involved, I'd like to make this programmatically in python to save time.

I tried to overwrite the .tail property of a bone but it didn't save it or something. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to switch to the object mode.

In a python console, enter something like this. Make sure to change the name of the armature to what you have. The .tail property is not what you want to overwrite, it's the tail_local.

```
for bone in bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].bones:
    if bone.parent is not None:
        bone.parent.tail_local = bone.head_local
```

Then switch to edit mode to see the effect

---

If your parents can have multiple children and if you only want to move those tails that have a single children, you can try to use this code snippet:

```
parent2children = {}

for bone in bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].bones:
    if bone.parent is not None:
        if bone.parent.name in parent2children:
            parent2children[bone.parent.name].append(bone)
        else:
            parent2children[bone.parent.name] = [bone]


for name in parent2children:
    if len(parent2children[name]) == 1:
        parent = bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].bones[name]
        parent.tail_local = parent2children[name][0].head_local
```

make sure to switch to object mode first here as well