# Downloaded rigged blender mesh, oversized bones

Tags: rigging, armature, import

I downloaded a blender file which was supposed to include rig, animation, textures etc.

But when opening it I got the rig oversized and it seems that if I scale it, it scales the mesh too. Anyone knows a process to make this rig useable? I only need it to pose, I'm not doing animation.[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Scale  rig in edit mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot, it looks like the bones' heads (roots) are at the right place, but only their tails (tips) are somehow far away.
This looks like a rig from an external program that has been badly imported to Blender. Some programs don't have notions of start points and end points for bones, they are just unique points. That's why sometimes you have "leaf bones", to serve as visual endpoint for bones.

But when you import such rig with no tail to Blender, you need to recreate these tails somehow, and one solution for that is to just create each bone's tail at an arbitrary fixed distance from the head.

Theoretically, as long as the bones heads are in the right place, the tails locations doesn't impact how the rig functions, it's just visually unpleasing.

To fix that:

In edit mode, select all bones. Set your `Transformation Orientation` to `Local`, and your `Transform Pivot Point` to `Individual`.

Then scale your bones on their local Y axes by pressing <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>.

[image: settings]

There are also [scripts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/153630/53447) that can snap the parent bone tail to the child head, but that can break your rig if you don't know what you are doing. (and the one in my link is outdated.)

---

Where is that .blend from? I know some websites sometimes offer files that are generated by a conversion program rather by the artist who made the asset, be careful it's not that.

Comment: Thank you @LoLock for the detailed answer. It worked partially. What I mean by that is the selection on all the bones didn't affect the transformation of all of them in the same time so I had to do it one by one, but it's still a good solution. On the other hand scaling by Y was only moving the bones on the Y direction(same with any other axes) so I found in the Item proprieties (N shortcut) a bunch of transform options for the Head (X, Y,Z, Radius) and for the Tail ( X, Y, Z, Radius, Roll, Length, Envelope). The length was 100 for all of them and I input 2 for each bone.

Comment: I downloaded many assets a few days ago from multiple sites so I don't remember exactly the site where it was this one but I check each file for malware before opening and I only use them for my learning process so even if the sources are a bit obscure there shouldn't be any issue besides these details that I encounter and help me understand blender's functionality better.